# Powershell Looping with Mouse Automation

Tags: powershell, automation

I found a powershell script that does cursor automation for executing events, but I don't know how to put it in a loop without having to manually adjust x and y each time. There is more to the script but the only part changing is the beginning where a selection is being made.

```
$x = 2870
$y = -640
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($x, $y)
sleep -Seconds 01
$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000002, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000004, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Desired output would be for $y to be subtracted by 30 about 36x until I switch to the next page. The number 30 was chosen because that is the distance between the list of selections.
Would changing $y interfere with the rest of the script where I have specific locations for my cursor?

Comment: Both? You want your cursor to go diagonally? Or just down? I'm guessing you only want `$y` to go down by 30 so that the cursor jumps down your screen in a straight line clicking every 30 pixels, right?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician actually the thought hadn't occurred to me (it's been a long day). Yes, I just want my cursor to go down so $y would be just fine you are correct. Would I be looping the whole script or just the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `For` loop pretty simply. You want to set your initial coordinates, then just adjust `$y` on each iteration.

```
$x = 2870
$y = -640
for($i=0;$i -lt 36;$i++){
    [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($x, ($y-$i*30))
    sleep -Seconds 01
    $SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000002, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000004, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a few issues though. I placed the rest of the script inside the loop at the end, but when I run it the next selection isn't made. Could it be because the last position of the cursor is at $x = 1839 and $y = -527? Also what do you mean adjusting $y for each iteration? My script is simple to where it selects and just exports the file.

Comment: Without knowing the rest of your script I can't say what's wrong. If you are using the code I provided your mouse should end up at `$x = 2870` and `$y = -1690`. That loop seriously moves the pointer to a specified point, and assuming your `$SendMouseClick` stuff does what it implies it should click the mouse. I'm assuming the mouse event 2 is mouse button down, and 4 is mouse button up, simulating a click.

Comment: iteration means each time the loop is executed. adjusting $y changes where the mouse is vertically. so adjust $y on each iteration means that each time the loop is executed it moves the mouse vertically by 30 pixels.

Comment: it's literally a copy and paste of what is in the original post just with different x and y coordinates lol. Your code does work though without my meddling with it. Also thanks for breaking things down, this is my first time really interacting with powershell.

Comment: Just figured out the issue, had to include the preset $x and $y coordinates at the end as well, still not sure why but the rest of the script worked when that was added. Thanks again!

Comment: If this resolves your issue please accept the answer (green check mark to the left of the answer) to help future users with a similar issue find functional answers.